Sending message in Mattermost with priority from Go
I want to send message with priority from my bot on GO. I using github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/v6/model module. I tried many different options, but nothing worked. All messages come as usual, without priority, as it can be done in the GUI of the native client.

Here is the code from my last attempt. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?
package main

import (
    .....
    "github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/v6/model"
    .....
)

func sendMessage(logger zerolog.Logger, client *model.Client4, message string, channelID string, priority string) error {

    post := &model.Post{
        ChannelId: channelID,
        Message:   message,
    }
    post.AddProp("priority", priority)

    _, resp, err := client.CreatePost(post)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error().Err(err).Msg("Message sending error")
        return fmt.Errorf("Message sending error: %v", err)
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 201 {
        logger.Error().Int("status", resp.StatusCode).Msg("Failed to send message")
        return fmt.Errorf("Failed to send message. Status: %d", resp.StatusCode)
    }

    return nil
}

.....

func main() {
.....
    err := sendMessage(logger.With().Str("channel", ch.Name).Logger(), client, message, ch.ChannelID, "urgent")
.....
}

I tried using a newer module - github.com/mattermost/mattermost/server/public/model
Nothing worked either.
Thank you very much in advance!

Have you checked this question? Double check what you are sending with a remote server like Beeceptor

Checked. It's not corresponding with my question. I don't use native API (but it not work too), I use a module for Go. And I use lowercase

I found a solution to the problem myself:
post := &model.Post{
    ChannelId: channelID,
    Message:   message,
    Metadata: &model.PostMetadata{
        Priority: &model.PostPriority{Priority: &priority},
    },
}

